# Makefile order is never satisfied

Tags: docker, makefile

I have the following project Structure:

```
| .
| ..
| 
| Makefile
| a
  | .
  | ..
  | Dockerfile
  \ Makefile
\ b
  | .
  | ..
  | Dockerfile
  \ Makefile
```

a/Makefile:

```
all:
<TAB>docker build -t a-image .
```

b/Makefile:

```
all:
<TAB>docker build -t b-image .
```

b/Dockerfile:

```
FROM a-image
...
```

Makefile:

```
all: a b

a:
<TAB>make -C a/ all

b: a
<TAB>make -C b/ all
```

For some reason, when I run `make all` in the root directory of the ptoject, I never get `a` built and receive an error while building `b` as it depends on `a`.

```
...
pull access denied for a-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `For some reason, when I run make all in the root directory of the ptoject, I never get a built` Because `a` already exists, its an directory. make doesn't know anything about docker images. They should be PHONY targets.

Comment: Just a note, you should _always_ use the variable `$(MAKE)` when invoking a sub-make in a recipe, never the simple command `make`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make's principal mode of operations is around *files*.  Your Makefile says, if a file `a` doesn't exist, here are rules to create it; and if `b` doesn't exist, `a` must (build it if necessary), and here are rules to create it.

In your example, though, both `a` and `b` are directories that exist on disk.  Make is able to look at the disk and say "a filesystem entry named `a` already exists" and skip the corresponding rules.

If you're using GNU Make and are just trying to use Make as a script runner rather than a build system, you can declare the directory rules as [`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).  This will cause Make to ignore the fact that the files already exist, and always consider those rules out-of-date.

```makefile
# in the top-level Makefile, anywhere, unindented
.PHONY: a b
```

I might suggest a better approach is to embrace Make's file-oriented model.  Whenever you do something, make sure you create a file and update its timestamp with **touch**(1) to record that fact.  In `a/Makefile`, for example, you could use a sentinel file to record the image build

```makefile
.PHONY: all
all: .docker-build

.docker-build: Dockerfile
        docker build -t a-image .
        touch "$@"
```

Now in the parent Makefile, you know that `make -C a` will create `a/.docker-build`, and you can use that as the dependency target.

```makefile
.PHONY: all
all: b/.docker-build

a/.docker-build:
        $(MAKE) -C a

b/.docker-build: a/.docker-build
        $(MAKE) -C b
```

If you delete the `.PHONY` lines this will work with any Make implementation.